# Get cheapset prices in price table

Tags: mysql

I have a price table. I want to list the cheapest price of the products with the same IDs in my table. How can I do it?

```
Table Name : prices

userID| productsID  | price  | stock | maks
-------------------------------------------
 1    | C120221     |  100  | 3      | 1
 2    | C120221     |  200  | 5      | 5
 3    | BR120221    |  500  | 7      | 3
 4    | BR120221    |  600  | 9      | 0
 5    | BR120221    |  700  | 11     | 2
```

```
SQL

    SELECT
        MIN(price ) AS price ,
        GROUP_CONCAT(userID) AS userID
        FROM prices
        WHERE price > 0 
        GROUP BY productsID  
        ORDER BY price ASC
```

In this case I want to list all the info of the user with the cheapest price. In the current query, I can get the data in the productsID and price fields, but I cannot get the data in the userID, stock and max fields of the user with these data. Where is the problem?

Comment: Use window function in CTE. Or (for version 5.x) use NOT EXISTS.

Comment: *I want to list all the info of the user with the cheapest price* What if 2 different users set the same cheapest price?

Comment: I can buy the one with more stock as the cheapest

Comment: I am not interested in what you can buy. I have asked about the desired output in this case. Return all such users? if true - in one row or as separate rows? if only one of them - what precisely? selected by what additional criteria?

Comment: My priority is; I want the data of the users who are the cheapest among the prices, separated from other users. If it has the same price, the condition can be determined as the cheapest with the highest number of stocks.

Comment: *If it has the same price, the condition can be determined as the cheapest with the highest number of stocks.* Partial criteria, such users may have the same amount of stocks. PS. Replace table-type sample data with according CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO. The sample data must contain discussed "duplicated users"! Add desired output for this sample data as a table. Do not forget to specify what is precise MySQL version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably trying to find the line or lines that contain the lowest price.

```
SELECT
  prices.*
FROM
  (
    SELECT
      MIN(price) AS price,
      productsID
    FROM
      prices
    WHERE
      price > 0
    GROUP BY
      productsID
  ) AS t1
  JOIN prices ON prices.price = t1.price
  AND prices.productsID = t1.productsID
```